# Как убрать навсегда edgeBar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge

Просто изнасиловал этот навязчивый сервис панели поиска Edge посреди экрана...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Совет "снять флажок автоматического запуска" - флажок снят, но после закрытия Edge эта панель опять тут как тут.

Советовали зайти edge://settings/edgeBar - нет таких настроек в Edge (Версия 112.0.1722.68 (Официальная сборка) (64-разрядная версия)).

Как его убить так, чтоб больше не поднимался никогда?

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить такое решение:

> настройки => система и производительность
>
> > выключить флажок
> > "Продолжать работу фоновых приложений, когда Microsoft Edge закрыт"

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Попробовал. Не работает.